# Is there a way to catch any and all errors that may be thrown using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, adafruit-circuitpython

I am writing a GUI that interfaces with i2c sensors via USB. As a result, an error could be thrown at any stage if something happens to the sensor (e.g. something shorts due the sensors still being on a breadboard in development).

As it stands, if there is an error, the kernel will crash, but there is no indication to the user that the program has crashed (other than in the terminal running the python script) and you can still interact with the GUI but nothing actually happens.

I would like the program to automatically exit (or at least warn the user) when an error is thrown and execution is interrupted. Is there a nice way of doing this that doesn't involve including a `try` block in every operation involving the interface with the USB?

Comment: You could just put all of the code in the start of a `try` block, so that when it does crash, it tells you the error and **then** exits (in the `except` part). So instead of lots of `try` blocks you have one big one. At the very least you might be able to find the kind of error it is throwing (using this method), look that error type up, and find a better method of protection. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: Put everything into a function called `main()` and call *that* inside a `try` / `except Exception as exc:`. You can then ignore it with `pass`, but it might be better to `print(exc)` first.

Comment: I'm not sure the 'wrap everything' method works as I am writing the code object-oriented. i.e. the application is a class (`Application`) and there are methods within the class for all the different functions in the GUI. I tried wrapping the call of the class (`app = Application()`) and the `app.mainloop` portions in a `try` block but that didnt work.

Comment: I reckon there really isn't too many options then. (not sure if this what you already tried) Maybe put the method that gets all the data (`app.getDataFromSensors()`) in it's own `try` block. That way when you go get the data from the sensors the error is constrained just to `app.getDataFromSensors()`, and then you can display message, quit, etc. . I don't think you are going to be able to avoid the `try` blocks that much though.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably the best option. I was hoping for something a little more elegant that would capture anything and everything that could appear, but this should suffice.